# How to get log from NonCatalogLogger in weblogic10.x

Tags: log4j, weblogic

d party lib and found that it traces it state via weblogic.logging.NonCatalogLogger but I don't see any string in log. How can I receive log from these classes?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running within Weblogic server, the NonCatalogLogger prints to the weblogic server logs. See [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/i18n/writing.html#NonCatalogLogger_APIs) for more.

If this is not reflecting in the server logs, check whether the Java class is logging at Logger.info() or Logger.debug() and ensure the Log Level in admin console is also set at the same DEBUG or INFO.
It might be set at ERROR or WARNING.

If you want to use the NonCatalogLogger outside of a running weblogic server:

As per http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/i18n/writing.html#wp1145513 and the API at http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/javadocs/weblogic/logging/NonCatalogLogger.html

you have to initialize your JVM with -Dweblogic.log.FileName=logfilename